# Display long text fields as type text input not as textarea on node forms

Tags: 8, theming

I have some fields which are configured as long text fields, which I need to display as `<input type="text />` instead of `<textarea></textarea>`.

I'm trying to find the correct naming convention so that I can have some theme overrides in my templates folder.

Is that the correct approach?  Is there documentation about overriding specific field outputs on edit screens?

Comment: You can't "theme" a Form API input field the same way as frontend output fields. You have to create your own module and implement a [custom field widget](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal textfield widget can only be applied to string fields.
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.4/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/StringTextfieldWidget.php#L9

However it's not a big deal to alter its definition and make it support long strings.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info_alter().
 */
function HOOK_field_widget_info_alter(array &$info) {
  $info['string_textfield']['field_types'][] = 'string_long';
}
```

After having this done it should be possible to assign textfield widget to long text fields on "Manage form display" page.

Comment: Nice.  That did it!  Thank you.